# leaked windows DecorView@666372[] that was originally added here

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i got a problem when trying to send data to server. it says leaked windows that was originally added here. here is my code

```
public class Feedback extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner topic;
    EditText subject, feedback;
    Button btnsend;
    List<String> listTopic;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listarray;
    String topik, subj, nup, feed;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String feed_url = "http://ds.bki.co.id:7777/ds/android/feedback.php";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Feedback.this);

        listTopic = new ArrayList<String>();
        listTopic.add("Interface");
        listTopic.add("Menu");
        listTopic.add("Features Request");
        listTopic.add("Bugs");
        listTopic.add("Others");

        topic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        listarray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), simple_dropdown_item_1line, listTopic);
        listarray.setDropDownViewResource(simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        topic.setAdapter(listarray);

        topic.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                topik = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subJect);
        feedback =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.feedBack);
        btnsend =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);



        btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subj = subject.getText().toString();
                feed = feedback.getText().toString();
                nup = SaveSharedPreference.getNup(getApplicationContext());

                Log.d("a", subj);
                Log.d("b", feed);
                Log.d("c", nup);
                Log.d("d", topik);

                new SendFB().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private class SendFB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Feedback.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            if (subj.equals("")||feed.equals("")){
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Enter a valid NUP and Password");
                displayAlert("input_error");
            }
            else
            {
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, feed_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            if (code.equals("Feedback success")) {
                                builder.setTitle("Feedback success...");
                                builder.setMessage(message);
                                displayAlert(code);
                            } else {
                                builder.setTitle("Feedback Failed...");
                                builder.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
                                displayAlert(code);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        params.put("Nup", nup);
                        params.put("topik", topik);
                        params.put("subject", subj);
                        params.put("feedback", feed);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(Feedback.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void displayAlert(final String code) {
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if (code.equals("Feedback success")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }
                else if (code.equals("input_error")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }
                else if (code.equals("Feedback Failed...")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I used the same code for my other page and I didn't get error but when i implemented the same code I got an error and i don't know where is the error came from. can anybody help me?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: com.icul.bkiisee, PID: 31153
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:121)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:166)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:46)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:97)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:929)
    at com.icul.bkiisee.Feedback.displayAlert(Feedback.java:207)
    at com.icul.bkiisee.Feedback$SendFB.doInBackground(Feedback.java:132)
    at com.icul.bkiisee.Feedback$SendFB.doInBackground(Feedback.java:116)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

this is the error i got when running the application

Comment: In `onPause()` perform `pDialog.dismiss();`.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: You cant show a alertDialog in background thread .

Answer (score 1):

I removed the doInBackground and put the dialog inside the onClick button. it solved my problem

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Feedback.this);

        listTopic = new ArrayList<String>();
        listTopic.add("Interface");
        listTopic.add("Menu");
        listTopic.add("Features Request");
        listTopic.add("Bugs");
        listTopic.add("Others");

        topic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        listarray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), simple_dropdown_item_1line, listTopic);
        listarray.setDropDownViewResource(simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        topic.setAdapter(listarray);

        topic.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                topik = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subJect);
        feedback =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.feedBack);
        btnsend =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);



        btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subj = subject.getText().toString();
                feed = feedback.getText().toString();
                nup = SaveSharedPreference.getNup(getApplicationContext());

                if (subj.equals("")||feed.equals("")){
                    builder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                    builder.setMessage("Enter a valid Subject and Feedback");
                    displayAlert("error");
                }
                else
                {
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, feed_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                                if (code.equals("Feedback success")) {
                                    builder.setTitle("Feedback success...");
                                    builder.setMessage(message);
                                    displayAlert(code);
                                } else {
                                    builder.setTitle("Feedback Failed...");
                                    builder.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");
                                    displayAlert(code);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            params.put("Nup", nup);
                            params.put("topik", topik);
                            params.put("subject", subj);
                            params.put("feedback", feed);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    MySingleton.getInstance(Feedback.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
                }

            }
        });

    }


    public void displayAlert(final String code) {
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if (code.equals("Feedback success")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }
                else if (code.equals("error")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }
                else if (code.equals("Feedback Failed...")) {
                    subject.setText("");
                    feedback.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```